# Google Analytics Goals is not working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a following problem. I've set up goal in GA with following parameters:

[image]

And added an onclick event on a button:

```
ga('send','event','links','click','Ask');
```

But it doesn't track this event.

This is GA added on a website by tagmanager:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you are using the last version of google analytics as 'gtag' and using the old method to send event, thus *you need to change from :*

```
ga('send','event','links','click','Ask');
```

to

```
gtag('event', 'click', { 'event_category': 'links', 'event_label': 'Ask'});
```